# Failing to pass models correctly from collection view?

Tags: backbone.js

I've been staring at this for a while and trying various tweaks, to no avail.

Why am I getting a "this.model is undefined" error at

```
$(function(){


  window.Sentence = Backbone.Model.extend({ 

    initialize: function() {
      console.log(this.toJSON()) 
    }
  });

  window.Text = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Sentence,

    initialize: function(models, options){
      this.url = options.url;
    }
  });

  window.SentenceView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.template = _.template($('#sentence_template').html());
    },

    render : function(){
      var rendered = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
      $(this.el).html(rendered);
      return this;
    }
  })

  window.TextView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#notebook') ,

    initialize : function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },

    render : function(){
      this.collection.each(function(sentence){
        if (sentence === undefined){
          console.log('sentence was undefined');
        };

        var view = new SentenceView({model: sentence});
        this.$('ol#sentences').append(view.render().el);
      });

      return this;
    }
  });

  function Notebook(params){
    this.text = new Text(
      // models
      {}, 
      // params
      {
        url: params.url 
      }
    );


    this.start = function(){
      this.text.fetch();
      this.textView = new TextView({
        collection: this.text
      });
      $('body').append(this.textView.render().el);
    };
  }

  window.notebook = new Notebook(
    { 'url': 'js/mandarin.js' }
  );

  window.notebook.start();

})
```

There's an online version wher eyou can see the error in a console at:

http://lotsofwords.org/languages/chinese/notebook/

The whole repo is at:

https://github.com/amundo/notebook/

The offending line appears to be at:

https://github.com/amundo/notebook/blob/master/js/notebook.js#L31

I find this perplexing because as far as I can tell the iteration in `TextView.render` has the right `_.each` syntax, I just can't figure out why the `Sentence` models aren't showing up as they should.

Answer (score 1):

```
var view = new SentenceView({model: sentence});
```

I'm pretty sure when you pass data to a backbone view constructor, the data is added to the `Backbone.View.options` property.

Change this line

```
var rendered = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
```

to this

```
var rendered = this.template(this.options.model.toJSON());
```

and see if it works

**UPDATE**:

From the doco:

*When creating a new View, the options you pass are attached to the view as this.options, for future reference. There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: model, collection, el, id, className, and tagName*

So, disregard the above advice - the model should by default be attached directly to the object

Things to check next when debugging:

- confirm from within the `render()` method that `this` is actually the SentenceView object
- confirm that you are not passing in an undefined sentence here:

  ```
  var view = new SentenceView({model: sentence});
  ```

UPDATE2:

It looks like the collection is borked then:

```
this.textView = new TextView({
    collection: this.text
});
```

To debug it further you'll need to examine it and work out what's going on. When I looked in firebug, the collection property didn't look right to me.

You could have a timing issue too. I thought the fetch was asynchronous, so you probably don't want to assign the collection to the TextView until you are sure it has completed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid that didn't do the trick -- now I'm just getting an error about `this.options.model is undefined.`

Comment: I was able to confirm that `this` refers to `SentenceView`. 

But in fact `sentence` **is** undefined in the call within `TextView.render`. I inserted the check  in the code above.

Comment: Oops, the rest of that comment was cut off. 

The `sentence` object *is** undefined in in the call to `new SentenceView` within `TextView.render`. I added the check to the code above, which results in printing "sentence was undefined" to the console.

Comment: I think your final comment is right about really what's really going on here -- it's a synchronization problem.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone surfaces underscore.js collection methods for you so you can do this.  See if this works for you:

```
this.collection.each(function(sentence) {
  // YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Comment: Thanks, either approach seems to be equivalent but neither is fixing the problem with the undefined model.

Comment: If I run your public example, but break on that collection line, I can run this.collection.each(function(sentence) { alert(sentence.cid) }) in the console and see the sentence's cid.  So I think that your sentence param should be defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on line 48 of notebook.js shown below:

```
render : function(){
    _(this.collection).each(function(sentence){
    var view = new SentenceView({model: sentence});
    this.$('ol#sentences').append(view.render().el);
});
```

The problem is you are wrapping the collection and you don't have to.  Change it to

```
this.collection.each(function(sentence){ ...
```

hope that fixes it

EDIT:
OK i'm going to take another crack at it now that you mentioned timing in one of your comments

take a look at where you are fetching and change it to this:

```
this.start = function(){
    this.text.fetch({
        success: _.bind( function() {
            this.textView = new TextView({
                collection: this.text
            });
            $('body').append(this.textView.render().el);
        }, this)
    );
};
```

I typed this manually so there may be mismatching parentheses.  The key is that fetch is async.

Hope this fixes it

Comment: odd--when i run this (sorry for formatting) in the console i see the rendered output--chinese phrases with english translations   this.collection.each(function(sentence){
var view = new SentenceView({model: sentence});
this.$('ol#sentences').append(view.render().el);
});

Comment: Hi Tim, yeah I do too. At this point I'm thinking the problem has nothing to do with the rendering code, rather, it's to do with the timing of the initial population of the collection.

Comment: I think this is the exact answer that I posted earlier.  Unfortunately, I came to the same conclusion, seems like the SentenceView view should then get the model.  If you set up a breakpoint in the Backbone.js View constructor, you don't see the model in the options.  Can you change your public code example to use the method that we both suggest so that we can factor that into the debugging?

Comment: you're right Bill--you found the same thing before me.  My bad for not noticing.  I agree that if @pat can change the public example it may help in diagnosing.

Answer (score -2):

try using _.each

```
 _.each(this.collection, function(sentence){
    if (sentence === undefined){
      console.log('sentence was undefined');
    };

    var view = new SentenceView({model: sentence});
    this.$('ol#sentences').append(view.render().el);
  },this);
```